# Parsing Json Data string And Retrieve Specific Element

Tags: c#, json

My JSON string is:

```
string b = "\"{\"Response\":[{\"ResponseCode\":\"0\",\"ResponseMessage\":\"71a88836-57f0-4b0e-a59c-071ea6d6f1de\"}]}\"";
```

I want to retrieve value of `ResponseCode` and `ResponseMessage`.

When I tried something like this to parse my JSON string

```
var userObj = JObject.Parse(b);
```

I am getting Error such as:

> `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException`: 'Error reading `JObject` from `JsonReader`. Current `JsonReader` item is not an object: `String`. Path '', line 1, position 3.'

Please help me to retrieve `ResponseCode` And `ResponseMessage` from the given string.

Comment: remove the doublequotes surrounding the outer json brackets

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to trim the outer doublequotes, otherwise it is not a valid json format

```
var userObj = JObject.Parse(b.Trim('"'));
```

Then you can retrieve the data either by declaring a class matching the json format and deserializing it, or just accessing the properties dynamically

```
var response = (JArray)userObj["Response"];
string responseCode = response[0]["ResponseCode"].Value<string>();
string responseMessage = response[0]["ResponseMessage"].Value<string>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use create a class that matches the properties you expect. I think you want a Response-class with property ResponseCode and ResponseMessage.

If that's the case, you should remove the outer "Response" tag. Also the backslash should be removed and the double quotes should be replaced by single quotes.

Try this:

```
class Response
{
    public string ResponseCode { get; set; }
    public string ResponseMessage { get; set; }
}
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string body = @"{'ResponseCode':0,'ResponseMessage':'71a88836-57f0-4b0e-a59c-071ea6d6f1de'}";
    var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(body );
}
```